# TypeScript ES5 and ES6 transpiling in the same folder structure?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to combine ES5 and ES6 JavaScript in the same TypeScript folder structure?

I would like to create a backend using Node with ES6 and the front end code to target ES5.

A folder structure might look like this:

`src/backend (transpiles to ES6)
src/frontend (transpiles to ES5)`

Is this possible at all? If so what would the `tsconfig.json` file look like?

Comment: You'll need two different `tsconfig.json` files

Comment: And then use something like gulp to run the two different `tsconfig.json` files?

Comment: Depends, you can also have your IDE compile the source files using both of them.

Comment: Using a directory `backend` that contains a `tsconfig.json` file and a seperate folder `frontend` with its own config file works well especially with Atom-TypeScript it picks the files up by default. What IDE are you normally using @NitzanTomer?

Comment: I'm working with WebStorm, and had projects which contained several config files and it worked well. But if Atom works for you then you're good.